# How can I prove that A is the associated Matrix to g(x)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What are nice ways to prove that

$$A= I_{n}+w v^{T}$$ is the associated matrix of the following function
$$g (x)=x+\left(v^{T} x\right) w$$ and $v,w \in \mathbb R^n$

My idea is to show that A is just the picture of the unit vectors but somehow I am stuck.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $\left(v^{T} x\right) w$ doesn't use actual matrix multiplication all throughout (the dimensions don't fit, as $v^Tx$ is $1\times 1$ and $w$ is $n\times 1$). However, turning it around and writing $w\left(v^{T} x\right)$, now it does. So we don't need the parentheses any more, as matrix multiplication is associative, and we can instead just write $wv^Tx$.

This gives
$$
g(x) = x + wv^Tx = I_nx + wv^Tx = (I_n + wv^T)x
$$
which is what we wanted to show.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You only have to check that the matrix $B=w{\,}^{\mathrm t \mkern-1.5mu}v$ is the matrix of the linear map
$$h(x)=({}^{\mathrm t \mkern-1.5mu}v\,x)w.$$
So determine $B$  and the images of the canonical basis: $h(e_1),h(e_2),\dots,h(e_n)$, and compare with the columns of $B$.